# vanilla js SPA - how i can save current content when refrest the page?

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application

everyone, i'm trying to create a simple SPA in vanilla js. The code works correctly, but when i refresh the page code doesn't display current content but output **Cannot GET /...**

I'm trying to change window.route to my custom route, but it doesn't help

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="/" class="link">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact" class="link">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about" class="link">About</a></li>
    </nav>

    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
const content = document.querySelector("#content");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

const routes = {
  "/": "<h1>Hello world</h1>",
  "/contact": "<h1>contact contact</h1>",
  "/about": "<h1>about</h1>",
  404: "not found",
};

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
    route(e);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});

const route = (e) => {
  window.history.pushState({}, "", e.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const handleLocation = (e) => {
  const location = window.location.pathname;
  const html = routes[location];
  content.innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;
handleLocation();
```

Comment: You have two problems. 1st is that the server does not recognize any files in `/contact`. You need to make sure that every route gets routed to index.html.

After that you can look for `window.location.href` and based on that execute whatever code is necessary to display your "SPA" content.